# Is there a way to compare content of two text files using selenium?

Tags: selenium, automation

Is there a way to compare the content of two text files using selenium?
I want to compare content of two files using automation.

Comment: What kind of result do you expect?

Comment: Are you trying to compare the web pages, or file downloads triggered by clicking a link or submitting a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need Selenium for this as Selenium is a **browser** automation framework and browsers are mostly used for accessing web pages so I would recommend looking into file comparison solution for the programming language you're using for automation.

However if this is something you really need be aware that [IWebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_INavigation_GoToUrl.htm) function can be used for opening local files on the file system as well.

Once you open the file you can read its contents into a variable using [IWebDriver.PageSource](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebDriver_PageSource.htm) property

Example code (assumes [Selenium with C#](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/selenium_appium_c_nunit/) using [Chrome](http://chromedriver.chromium.org) browser)

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;

namespace selenium_csharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("c:/path/to/chromedriver/folder", "chromedriver.exe"));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file://c:/somefolder/file1.txt");
            var file1 = driver.PageSource;
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file://c:/somefolder/file2.txt");
            var file2 = driver.PageSource;
            if (file1.Equals(file2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Files are equal");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Files are not equal");
            }
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```